# Random matrices: Relation between leading eigenvector and a vector in culumn space

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvector

Let $X$ be a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with iid zero-mean random entries on and above the diagonal. Denote by $v$ the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $X$. Let $a$ be a fixed $n$-dimensional vector with similar-magnitude entries. Is it possible to show that $v$ and $b = Xa$ are weakly dependent? In particular, can one show that $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 b_i$ is small in magnitude? If you know any references where related problems are studied, please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar-magnitude"? Randomly drawn from the exact same distribution, so we get $n+1$ iid? Or only from any distribution that has the same mean and same standard deviation?

Comment: I assume that $a$ is a fixed non-random vector, with entries of the same magnitudes. For example, $a_i=1$ for all i.